# What is wrong with this regex for content_scripts?

Tags: regex, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I dont want it to run on tv.sme.sk. Why it still keeps coming up there

```
"content_scripts": [
{
  "matches": ["http://*.sme.sk/*"],
  "exclude_matches": ["http://tv.sme.sk/*"],
  "js": ["script.js"],
  "css": ["style.css"]
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked it on a minimal example and it looks like you found a bug in Chrome. Funny part is that only CSS is injected to `tv.sme.sk`, javascript injection works as expected and follows the `exclude_matches` setting. I've played with `include_globs` and `exclude_globs` options but no luck.

Your best option is to inject CSS using [insertCSS method](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html#method-insertCSS).

**EDIT**

Yepp, this is a [known bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=100106).